# How to use imagefill() from file?

Tags: php, gd

Thanks for looking at this question.

I wanted to know how can I use the GD function imagefill() to patch an image with another image.

`imagefill()` currently accepts resource of a color.

I can do that. But wanted to know how this can be done with a file.

I noticed a user note - But that didn't worked and took a long time for completion :-( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php#84288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay people, have figures it out...

One needs to use imagecopymerge() function to achieve what i was trying to.

Thanks to all the viewers!